# Unable to configure a simple Controller in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

All i am trying to do is print a simple Hello world message , using a JSP page but when i try to do it,i get a 404 not found error  as shown below [image]

[image]

**this is my project structure, shown in the above diagram**

```
package com.example.MailSender;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.MailSender","com.example.MailSender.Controller"})
public class MailSenderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MailSenderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**the main application class is as shown above**

```
package com.example.MailSender.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping("/world")
    public String sample()
    {
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

**A very simple controller that i coded is shown above**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Basic config successful!!!</h1>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**A very simple JSP page to show the message**

```
server.port=9090
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/src/main/resources/static
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**this is the application.properties file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MailSender</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MailSender</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**the pom.xml file**

**i am unable to understand where i am going wrong, please help me out, why am i getting a 404 error ??
i belive http://localhost:9090/hello/world is a valid url**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues.

1. You need to add this dependency to your pom file

```xml
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. `/src/main/resources/static` is meant to hold static files such as `html` and `css`

- Create directory `src/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`
- Move your jsp into the above directory
- Update prefix `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/`

https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/

Answer (score 0):

Put samples.jsp in "resources/templates"

Answer (score -1):

You muste enable the mvc configuration. Create a class config :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class Config {

}
```

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-enablewebmvc-annotation.html

Comment: Having `spring-boot-starter-web` enables MVC, via auto-configuration